# How to arrange pixels in pairs based on their similarity

Tags: sorting, graphics, similarity, pixel

what I want to achieve is a transition between two image files. The pixels from the image A move and rearrange themselves to form the image B. Imagine a cloud of particles (that is made from the A image's pixels) that forms into the picture B.

So far I have thought of going through all the pixels in image A and comparing them to pixels in image B; pixels that are the most similar are taken out of the arrays (with their x,y coordinates, too) and put into another array. So, in the end, I have pairs of pixels from both images that are similar. Then I only have to create the animation / possible color balancing (obviously all the pairs won't consist of identical pixels), which is fairly easy.

The problem is the algorithm that finds pixel pairs. For a small 100px x 100px image it would take 50 005 000 comparisons, for larger it would be impossible.

Dividing pictures in clusters? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you're likely to achieve the best result matching up pixels by hue first, then saturation, finally luminance. If I'm right, then your best bet for optimization would be to convert to HSV first. Once there, you can just sort your pixels and binary search the results to find your pairs.

I'd say you'd may want to additionally search a fixed window around the result you find, to match up pixels that are least distance away from each other. That may make the resulting transition more coherent.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), which reduces the amount of actual comparisons for 100x100 pixels to 10000 - and after that you have O(n^3) time for finding the optimal matches. Basically, give each pixel combination a "cost" based on similarity and then send the (inverted) cost matrix through the algorithm to get the optimal assignment of pixels from A to pixels from B.

But it still might be too much computation for too little gain, depending on whether you need real time. I.e. this kind of work doesn't necessarily need an *optimal* match, just *good enough* - still, it may work as a point of origin in terms of finding less computationally intensive methods.

See bottom of the linked article for implementations in various languages - it's not entirely trival to implement.

Comment: Since I can't upvote or comment on Chris' answer yet, I'll just comment that his solution is a great example of the aforementioned good enough - and also an example of how I shouldn't answer questions when I'm in think-complicated-mode.